# cannot find symbol - method connectionStringSetting() when specified in CosmosDB annotation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a very basic Azure Function HTTP Trigger in Java which will write a record into CosmosDB when the API call is made; however, I get the following error when I try to specify `connectionStringSetting` within the `@CosmosDBOutput` annotation. Note, I am simply trying to test locally so DBs, collections, etc have not been created directly in Azure yet.

My `@CosmosDBOutput` annotation looks like this:

```
@CosmosDBOutput(name = "document", databaseName = "YourDatabaseName", containerName = "myContainer", connectionStringSetting="myConnectionString", connection = "CosmosDBConnection") OutputBinding<Subscriber> subscriber, final ExecutionContext context)
```

My `local.settings.json` looks like this:

```
 {
   "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
     "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
     "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
     "CosmosDBConnection": "YOUR_COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING",
     "connectionStringSetting": "myConnectionString"
   }
 }
```

I have tried different things like removing connectionStringSetting from local.settings.json and only specifying in the annotation, vice versa, removing all together but nothing seems to work. When I hover over the red squiggly lines in IntelliJ it tells me that it "cannot resolve method connectionStringSetting" on my annotation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Java Version: 21
azure-functions-java-library version: 3.0.0
azure-functions-maven-plugin: 1.23.0
```

Comment: seems like your issue is that you have `CosmosDBConnection`, which would be redundant since your `connectionStringSetting` has a reference to your connection string, right? What happens when you remove `CosmosDBConnection`?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I get the same error: cannot find symbol - method connectionStringSetting()

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `connectionStringSetting()` in my code as per [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv4&pivots=programming-language-java), I was also getting same error,

```
Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] */javafunc/src/main/java/com/function/Function.java:[30,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method connectionStringSetting()
[ERROR]   location: @interface com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.CosmosDBOutput
[ERROR] */javafunc/src/main/java/com/function/Function.java:[26,13] annotation @com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.CosmosDBOutput is missing a default value for the element 'connection'
```

[image]

I used `connection` in place of `connectionStringSetting` and it worked for me.

Microsoft document needs correction. I have raised a document correction [request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/117081).

**#My Code:**

```java
package com.function;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.OutputBinding;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.CosmosDBOutput;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;

public class Function {

    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @CosmosDBOutput(
                name = "database",
                databaseName="javadb",
                containerName = "data",
                connection = "COSMOSDB_connectionstring")
                OutputBinding<String> out,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        final int id = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());

        final String jsonDocument = "{\"id\":\"" + id + "\", " +
                                    "\"description\": \"" + name + "\"}";

        context.getLogger().info("Document to be saved: " + jsonDocument);

        out.setValue(jsonDocument);

        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body("Document saved successfully: "+jsonDocument)
        .build();
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "COSMOSDB_connectionstring":"AccountEndpoint=https://javafuncdb.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;"
  }
}
```

**`pom.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.function</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafunc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.28.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>3.0.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>javafunc</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                   
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

**

```
Document saved successfully: {"id":"1043435924", "description": "Vivek"}
```

**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you happen to have an example of your local.settings.json? Just want to see how that needs to be constructed for connection to work.

Comment: @supermariowhan Updated the answer with `local.settings.json`.

Comment: what version of azure-functions-maven-plugin are you using?

Comment: @supermariowhan I am using `1.28.0` version. Updated the answer with my `pom.xml` file.